# Cannot locate the volume file on the host machine?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I cannot locate my volume on machine after created. It should be locate on /var/lib/docker/volumn but nothing there except the files metadata.db and backingFsbBlockDev. No Error or exceptions display after running command.

```
   docker volume create TEST
      (out) TEST
   docker inspect -f "{{json .Mounts}}" vol-test | jq .
      (out) [
      (out) {
      (out)  "Type": "volume",
      (out)  "Name": "d46292f7b7fc75eacffb38d01c810317e5d24c6dcc45f008f9c42451e39c32f5",
      (out)  "Source": 
      (out) "/var/lib/docker/volumes/d46292f7b7fc75eacffb38d01c810317e5d24c6dcc45f008f9c42451e39c32f5/_data",
      (out) "Destination": "/data",
      (out) "Driver": "local",
      (out) "Mode": "",
      (out) "RW": true,
      (out) "Propagation": ""
      (out) }
      (out) ]
  ls /var/lib/docker/volumes/
      (out) backingFsBDev metadata.db
```

Do you have any ideas for this case, how to locate to volume file on my machine (Ubuntu 20.04)? thank you so much

Comment: If something is in a Docker named volume, you're not supposed to directly access it from the host (and you can't on non-Linux platforms).  Use a bind mount instead.

Comment: When I run `sudo touch test-file` as [this tutorial](https://blog.container-solutions.com/understanding-volumes-docker), i failed to located the folder, so there was no change happened on the container. I think this tutorial is outdated. Many thanks.

Comment: You should pretty much never need to look inside `/var/lib/docker` at all, and the various `docker ... inspect` commands tend to print out low-level information that's not especially useful.  If you `docker run -v vol-test:/data --rm busybox ls /data` you should be able to see the volume contents from a different container.

Comment: Definitely this command is what i seek. I can mount a directory from host to docker. Thank you.